# Automating the reset of Max ID in PostgreSQL Table after CSV import in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

In my application, I use CSV import to add content, however, after a CSV import, when I try to create a new object, I get an error saying that the IDs conflict. I have figured out how to solve this problem manually after every import by:

```
 SELECT setval('products_id_seq', max(id))
 FROM products;
```

While this works, I was wondering if there was a way to automate it after I submitted the CSV table, but I am not sure how to use SQL in a ruby function, any help would be appreciated!!

Note: For my CSV input I used the method described in [this railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel)

Comment: By **automate**, I assume you mean something other than adding the above query to your CSV import code, but I'm not quite sure what else that could be. Please explain in more detail what you're looking for.

Comment: @KenHampson yes that is what I meant, is it possible to add the query to a ruby function? And if so, do you put it in the controller or the model? Thanks and let me know if you need additional information/what I should add.

Comment: What are you using to interact with *Postgres*? *ActiveRecord*?

Comment: @KenHampson yes I am using active record, is there a way to add this to the function? Do I do it in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answers to my questions in the comments (whether it's possible to add the query to a *Ruby* function and that you're using *ActiveRecord* to interact with *Postgres*), my answer is as follows:

I believe the best bet would be to add your query above to your *Ruby* code after you do the importing of the *CSV*.

Regarding your comment question, yes, it is possible to add the query to a *Ruby* function.

With *ActiveRecord*, while they discourage raw *SQL* in general, you should be able to use the `connection` on your *model* object to run the query.

So, something like this should work (not tested, as I don't have a *Rails* setup handy):

```
query = "SELECT setval('products_id_seq', max(id))
         FROM products"

TheModel.connection.execute(query)
```

where `TheModel` is the name of the model object whose connection you want to use (the one connected to the DB on which you're doing the *CSV* import).

Comment: Thanks! I will try it when i get back home